# iTC: Version Release - Manually release this version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have a question about releasing a app.

If I choose the "**Manually release this version**", does that means that nobody can download my app, not even me - or can I still download it?

Comment: If it's a new app, it won't show up in the App Store until you release it. If it's an Update, the current version will still be there until you release the updated version. So, no, even you cannot download your new/updated app until you release it.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you for your reply. Is there any way I can release this for just me, and then make it public? Or can I only choose for everybody or nobody?

Comment: You can add yourself as a TestFlight user... submit your app and make it available for TestFlight.

Comment: @DonMag Good idea! Thanks :-)